# Simple Python Program Loop Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

Can anyone help me see what's going wrong in this? I'm getting an error at the end: "NameError: name 'age' is not defined". I'm just getting into Python and programming in general, and don't see what to change to fix it.

```
import random

def greeting():
    print("Hi there, welcome to the world's simplest tv suggestion program!")
    print("")

def get_birth_year():
    birth_year = 0
    birth_year = (input("Please enter your year of birth: "))
    is_valid = is_year_valid(birth_year)
    while not is_valid:
        birth_year = input("Please enter a four digit year of birth: ")
        is_valid = is_year_valid(birth_year)
    birth_year = int(birth_year)
    return birth_year


def is_year_valid(birth_year):
    try:
        birth_year = int(birth_year)
        is_valid = True
    except ValueError:
        is_valid = False
    return is_valid


def calculate_age(birth_year):
    age = 0
    age = 2018 - birth_year
    return age


def show_rec_output(age):
    print("Based on your age, a good Netflix show for you to watch would be:")
    adult = ["Master of None", "Unbreakable Kimmy Schmidt", "Black Mirror", "Godless",
             "Dear White People", "Grace and Frankie", "Jessica Jones"]
    all_ages = ["The Crown", "The Great British Bake Off", "Jessica Jones",
                "Sherlock", "A Series of Unfortunate Events", "Big Mouth"]
    if age >= 18:
        print(random.choice(adult))
    else:
        print(random.choice(all_ages))


def another_rec():
    second_rec = ""
    second_rec = (input("Would you like another recommendation Y/N: "))
    while second_rec == str("Y"):
        show_rec_output(age)
        second_rec = (input("Would you like another recommendation? Y/N: "))
    else:
        print("Go make some popcorn!")


def main_module():
    greeting()
    birth_year = get_birth_year()
    age = calculate_age(birth_year)
    show_rec_output(age)
    another_rec()

main_module()
```

The assignment I'm trying to complete requires one piece of input, one piece of output, two loops, input validation, and everything in modules.

Comment: Please give us the whole traceback, not just a description of the error. The traceback tells you exactly which line the error comes from, and how you got there, which is usually very important to debugging.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
def another_rec():
    second_rec = ""
    second_rec = (input("Would you like another recommendation Y/N: "))
    while second_rec == str("Y"):
        show_rec_output(age)
```

You don't have `age` here, but you're trying to use it anyway.

To fix it, you want to do the exact same thing you do with `show_rec_output`. First, add an `age` parameter to the `another_rec` function:

```
def another_rec(age):
```

… and then, pass the value in from `main_module`:

```
show_rec_output(age)
another_rec(age)
```